# How to use KVM to boot a VM from image file in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm

I got a KVM VM image from a friend. I could not find how to use KVM to boot a VM from an existing image file (.img) in Internet.

How can I use KVM to boot a VM from the existing image file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From console: `qemu-system-i386 ubuntu.img --enable-kvm -monitor stdio -m 2048 -vga cirrus -vnc :0`

From virt-manager: you need to specify the type of image in your VM configuration (raw, qcow2, ...)